# Input class displays correctly, button class does not

Tags: css

I'm working on a button, which is a rescaled image. The CSS applies correctly when I use `<input>`, but not when I use that same CSS for `<button>`.

The input tag:

```
<input type="image" name="app_ref" value="{$value['id']}" class="resize-app" src="{$value['img']}" alt="{$value['title']}">
```

However, POSTing this returns the coordinates of where the image was clicked, not the value I'm requesting.

[image: CSS working]

The button tag:

```
<button type='submit' name='app_ref' value='{$value['id']}' class='resize-app'><img src='{$value['img']}'></button>
```

Works as intended, except for the fact that it no longer displays the resized images, but the image with the original dimensions.

[image: CSS not working as intended]

I'm guessing you'd need to make a separate class for the button style? Though I'm trying to avoid in-line scripting, I cannot move the {$value['img']} to the CSS file, assuming the URL needs to be added to the stylesheet. The image is stored in a base64 format.

```css
.resize-app {
  height: 270px;
  width: 270px;
  border-radius: 48px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Check all your's css looking for `.resize-app` and -if it has- a `input.resize-app`, remove the `input`

Comment: Unless you show us the CSS, any answer will be a guess.

Comment: Resize img too `.resize-app img {max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%}`... or better, generate images in max size 270x270px.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add the stylesheet.

Comment: Can you provide a working code to exemplify your question? So we can stop to guess and work on that to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is only targeting the `button` element. To restrict the width of the image you would need something along these lines:

```css
.resize-app {
  height: 270px;
  width: 270px;
  border-radius: 48px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.resize-app img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button type='submit' name='app_ref' value='{$value[' id ']}' class='resize-app'>
  <img src='https://placehold.it/500x500'>
</button>
```